# Implicit typecasting not working for template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have two structs, A & B, such that B can be cast into A and I have defined the `operator+` for A.

```
struct A
{
  float x;
  A(float _x) : x(_x) {}
};

struct B
{
  float x;
  operator A()
  {
    return A{x};
  }
};

A operator+ (A left, A right)
{
  return A(left.x+right.x);
}
```

Without defining the `operator+` for B, the compiler knows to implicitly cast B objects to A and then add them. Which means the following works
`B b1 = {1.0f}; B b2 = {2.0f}; A a = b1 + b2`

However, when I convert my structs to template classes and try to perform the same operation on Ds instead of Bs, I get an error:

> error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'D' and 'D')

```
template<typename T>
struct C
{
  T x;
  C<T>(T _x) : x(_x) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct D
{
  T x;
  operator C<T>()
  {
    return C<T>(x);
  }
};

template<typename T>
C<T> operator+ (C<T> left, C<T> right)
{
  return C<T>(left.x+right.x);
}
```

Why does converting my structs into templates cause the implicit casting to stop working?

Comment: I'll bet you could remove 90% of the code here and still show the problem. And with less code you might see the solution for yourself.

Comment: You have defined `operator+` for the A<T>, but not for B<..>.

Comment: The xy and yx are of type B and you did not define operator + for class B

Comment: @Pete Becker I have simplified the code but I still don't see the solution. I think that my original post made it very unclear what I was asking so hopefully it is now much clearer.

Comment: @Gupta I was trying to show that you don't always need to define the operator for class B. I realise that my original question was unclear on this so I have edited it.

Comment: @Jarod42 My original question wasn't clear, but these were not the problem I was trying to ask about. I have edited my question so it is much clearer. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Well done. But while I'm picking on you: "implicitly cast B objects to A" -- there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The issue here is about wanting the implicit **conversion** from `B<T>` to `A<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that your operator is template, and so should match its argument, implicit conversion cannot be applied for deduction.

`friend` is your friend :)

```
template<typename T>
struct C
{
  T x;
  C(T _x) : x(_x) {}

  friend C operator+ (C left, C right) // Function is no longer template
  {
      return C(left.x + right.x);
  }
};
```

Now, you can do `c + c`, `c + d`, `d + c`.

friend functions have special rules with ADL, so for `d + d`, we don't look at `friend operator+(C,C)`.

So we need another `friend` function in `D`:

```
template <typename T>
struct D
{
  T x;
  operator C<T>() { return C<T>(x); }

  friend C<T> operator+ (D left, D right)
  {
    return C<T>(left) + C<T>(right);
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cf7bf2cefe1387b)